# Fn::Foreach with intrinsic function parameter | Fn::GetAZ | could not find a collection

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to dynamically generate resources based on `Fn::GetAZs`' collection:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'
Resources:
  Fn::ForEach::CreateSecurityGroups:
    - 'AZIndex'
    - Fn::Split: [",", Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"]
    - Fn::Sub: SecurityGroup${AZIndex}
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: 'SecurityGroup-${AZIndex}'
        GroupName: 
          Fn::Sub: 'SecurityGroup-${AZIndex}'
```

However the stack creation fails, and within the events the error is:

`Transform AWS::LanguageExtensions failed with: Could not find a collection or could not be resolved for Fn::ForEach`

How can this be fixed?

###### Other approaches I've tried

All reproduce the same sort of error.

```
- Fn::Join:
  - ","
  - Fn::GetAZs: ''

- Fn::GetAZs:
    Ref: 'AWS::Region'

- Fn::GetAZs: ''
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by the usage of the inline `Fn::Sub`, which is not supported for non pseudo-parameters. This should work:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'
Resources:
  Fn::ForEach::CreateSecurityGroups:
    - 'AZIndex'
    - Fn::Split: [",", Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"]
    - 'SecurityGroup${AZIndex}'
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: 'SecurityGroup-${AZIndex}'
        GroupName: 
          Fn::Sub: 'SecurityGroup-${AZIndex}'
```